# Context in Type Theory

Tags: type-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am reading a [book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/computation-and-reasoning-9780198538356?cc=es&lang=en&) on type theory. On page 105, the author says that

> If one views valid contexts as theories (in the sense of ordinary logics) a consistent context corresponds to a consistent theory in the traditional sense.

Then the author gives the following definition:

> **Definition** (**Consistent Contexts**) A valid context $\Gamma$ is consistent if and only if not very $\Gamma$-formula
>    is provable in $\Gamma$, or equivalently, if and only if $\perp$ is not provable in $\Gamma$.

If I understand correctly, this implies that (a) not every context ($\Gamma$ : ctx) is consistent in type theory, and (b) if $\Gamma$ is consistent, then we won't be able to have both $x_1:A$ and $x_2:\neg A$ as assumptions, as they result in $\perp$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (a) not every context $(Γ : \text{ctx})$ is consistent in type theory

Indeed, the context $x : \bot$ is inconsistent.

> (b) if $\Gamma$ is consistent, then we won't be able to have both $x_1:A$ and $x_2:\neg A$ as assumptions, as they result in $\bot$

Yes, but this is just a trivial example. Inconsistencies can be sneakier.
To level up, try to think of a context with 3 assumed propositions that is inconsistent, but removing any one of them results in a consistent context.